# How can I determine what weapons I'm missing?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is there some quick and easy way to determine which TF2 weapons I'm missing?

Comment: Hm. Since backpack parsing is already available, I wouldn't put it past someone to write some script somehow.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: That's a good idea, actually. I'll star this question and come back to it later.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to [tf2items.com](http://www.tf2items.com) and enter you profile ID. (If you don't have a profile ID set up, just copy the link to your community page)

It will show 3 different tabs, the last one - *checklist* - should be exactly what you need.

In order for this to work, your profile needs to be public though.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of sites that examine your backpack (and I've written a [user-javascript that links them from steamcommunity profile](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/64791); although [Enhanced Steam extension](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) also links to some of those sites), and indeed [TF2Items](http://www.tf2items.com/) is the most famous one.

<strike>However, today I found [TF2LS](http://tf2ls.com/), and I think it has the most concise and easy-to-read interface for seeing what items you are missing and what items you have too much. I believe this is the best site to answer your question.</strike> The site is now offline.

Answer (score 3):

Best way I can think of is to enter your item backpack in game, sort by class, and then compare to this list: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Weapons

Other than that, you can see all of the weapons (and hats) in the item store.